# Data Table Solution To New Variables By Group

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

dataHAVE=data.frame("student"=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
                    "score"=c(0,8,8,7,9,4,9,2,7),
                    "time"=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3))


dataWANT=data.frame("student"=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
                    "score"=c(0,8,8,7,9,4,9,2,7),
                    "time"=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),
                    "score3"=c(1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1),
                    "timescore3"=c(1,1,1,3,3,3,2,2,2),
                    "score7"=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                    "timescore7"=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2))




dataHAVE[, score3 := ifelse(score<=3,
                               time[which.min(score<=3)],
                               time[which.max(time)]), by=student]
```

I have 'dataHAVE' and want to generate 'dataWANT'

1) score3 equals to 1 if a student has any score less than or equals to 3; otherwise 0

2) score7 equals to 1 if a student has any score less than or equals to 7; otherwise 0

3) timescore3 equals to the minimum time value at which a student scores a 3 or less; if a student does not score a 3 or less as indicated by score equals to 3, then timecsore3 is the maximum time for that student.

4) timescore7 equals to the minimum time value at which a student scores a 7 or less; if a student does not score a 7 or less as indicated by score equals to 7, then timecsore7 is the maximum time for that student.

My attempt at this shows above but does not work and please note, I attempted Base R and `dplyr` but the dataset is so big that these take a very long time. A data.table solution is ideal.

NEW DATA TO HANDLE MISSING::

```
dataHAVE=data.frame("student"=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5),
                    "score"=c(0,8,8,7,9,4,9,2,7,NA,4,7,NA,NA,NA),
                    "time"=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3))
```

Updated DATA with missing 'time'

```
dataHAVE=data.frame("student"=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7),
                    "score"=c(0,8,8,7,9,4,9,2,7,NA,4,7,NA,NA,NA,6,9,3,NA,NA,NA),
                    "time"=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,NA,2,NA,NA,NA,NA))
```

Comment: The second condition is not clear `library(data.table)setDT(dataHAVE)[, c("score3", "score7") := .(+(any(score <=3)), +(any(score <=7))), .(student)];dataHAVE[, c("timescore3", "timescore7") := .(min(first(time[score <=3]), time[which.min(score)]), min(first(time[score <=7]), time[which.min(score)])), .(student)]`

Comment: @akron Quite Amazing! Last inquiry regarding: how to do this and ignore missing NA values?

Comment: in your example, i am not getting an NA, but if there are NA elements in score, `na.rm = TRUE` in `min` and `max`

Comment: @akrun thanks a bunch when I try on my data with missing vals and I add na.rm=TRUE like min(time[sc3], na.rm=TRUE) i get:: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: It could be a case where all elements are NA for that particular. group, in that case, you need `if(all(is.na(time[sc3]))) NA else min(time[sc3], na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: @akrun So then I have:: if(all(is.na(time[sc3]))) NA else min(time[sc3], na.rm = TRUE) else max(score) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the logic showed, it can be done with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dataHAVE)[,c("score3", "timescore3", "score7", "timescore7") := {
                   sc3 <- score <=3
                   sc7 <-  score <= 7
                   tsc3 <- if(any(sc3)) min(time[sc3]) else max(time)
                   tsc7 <- if(any(sc7)) min(time[sc7]) else max(time)
         .(+(any(sc3)), tsc3, +(any(sc7)),tsc7 )}, .(student)]
```

---

If there are missing values, then use

```
setDT(dataHAVE)[,c("score3", "timescore3", "score7", "timescore7") := {
                   sc3 <- score <=3 & !is.na(score)
                    sc7 <-  score <= 7 & !is.na(score)
                    tsc3 <- if(any(sc3)) min(time[sc3], na.rm = TRUE) else max(time, na.rm = TRUE)
                    tsc7 <- if(any(sc7)) min(time[sc7], na.rm = TRUE) else max(time, na.rm = TRUE)
          .(+(any(sc3)), tsc3, +(any(sc7)),tsc7 )}, .(student)]
```

Comment: I added updated data file to address the issue I raise which has some NA per student and a student with all NA.

Comment: @bvowe With your example data upddated, it is working for me

Comment: thank you very much. Thank you but for student 5 all new variables should be 'NA' because there are no data.

Comment: I think I find the issue and that is: some student's are missing data on time! I tried out a solution of min((time, na.rm=TRUE)[sc7], na.rm = TRUE) but this was not successful

Comment: @bvowe Can you please update with another example. thanks

Comment: thanks so much for all your help- you are incredibly helpful!! i added a new example

Comment: Please give me some time, on a call

Comment: @bvowe there is `Inf` on 'time' column because it is all NA for that group.  It is working with a warning though